# Как открыть библиотеку с кнопками и др. в Xcode

Tags: xcode, swiftui

[image: открытое окно с помощью [+]]

Проблема заключается в отсутствии раздела с кнопками и вообще с всем что нужно для проектирования в SwiftUI.
Я искал в настройках, перезапускал Xcode, перезагружал компьютер, смотрел на stackOverflow но так проблему и не решил.
Помогает только создание нового проекта и то ненадолго, потом снова раздел с кнопками исчезает!

Версия Xcode 13.3.1.

Answer (score 0):

Вы создали storyboard? На каком файле сейчас фокус в навигаторе? Думаю на каком то .swift, а нужно создать/открыть storyboard и тогда все у вас появится

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]